# Grunt Sass - Output erros on console

Tags: sass, gruntjs

How can I set Sass to validade my scss files and output any errors on console?

I am writing this class in order to test it:

```
.test {
    color: #ff3;
    border-right: 5px solid blueee
    aaaaaa
}
```

And when I hit Save, the console shows:

```
>> File "scss/app.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done, without errors.
```

But obviously as you can see, there is an error on my scss file. How can I display that on console?

Comment: That's just it, there aren't any errors being raised by Sass:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/8a7eb9d76ff07e19abe4.  Sass does not protect you from writing invalid CSS.

Comment: But I know there is a way to get your Sass validated and output the error on console, just like jshint does.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Sass at all:  what you wrote is perfectly valid in Sass.  You would need to validate the compiled CSS **after** your Sass has been compiled.

Comment: @cimmanon are sure what I wrote is perfectly valid Sass? lol

Comment: I just proved to you that your code compiles without error.  It is completely valid according Sass using the SCSS syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to try either a Sass linting tool or a CSS linting tool (or both) depending what it is you want to do.

- For Sass there is [grunt-scss-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-scss-lint)
- For Css there is [grunt-contrib-csslint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-csslint)

Comment: I think this might be the only solution.